# Adding styled component to child component is not working

Tags: css, reactjs, less, styled-components

I tried adding the styled component to the child component but the values are not changing at all.

Child component returns

```
  <a href='' className="displayCarft">{props.craftcolor}</a>
```

I am using the child component in parent component

```
   <div classname = 'container'>
      <Child color={props.color}/>
   </div>
```

i tried adding styled component

```
 const Styledcomp = styled(Child)`
 .displayCarft{
 color: green !important;
 }
  `

<div classname = 'container'>
      <Styledcomp color={props.color}/>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the className generated by the styled component to the Child component.

```
const Child = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <a href="" className="displayCarft">
        {props.craftcolor}
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: No I cannot pass child component is reused with other component

Comment: Can you update your code with exact structure that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As i guess you need two `Styledcomp` with different styles so try using props.
[Deeply read here](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

you can use

```
const Styledcomp = styled(Child)`
  ${(props) => prop.green && 'color: green}
  /* other styles here */
 `
```

Use green elements like this: `<Styledcomp green />`

Comment: what if i need to add only font size instead of color

Comment: code after && works if statement before it is true. So you can write font-size instead of color

Comment: [Check this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-inline-conditional-expressions-in-reactjs/)  and [this](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)